# Get parent entity id in CollectionType Admin

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sonata-admin, sonata

I am creating an entity **basketElement** which is linked to a parent entity **basket** via Sonata\Form\Type\CollectionType instantiated admin. When creating the entity **basketElement** I also need to call a function of a service which needs the id of entity **basket**.

For now, I have an admin:

```
class BasketAdmin extends AbstractAdmin {
    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper): void
    {
        $formMapper->with('basket.group.basketElements')
            ->add('basketElements', Sonata\Form\Type\CollectionType::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

And the basketElements field admin is as following:

```
class BasketElementAdmin extends AbstractAdmin {
    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper): void
    {
        $formMapper->with('basketElement.group.products')
            ->add('basket', Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelHiddenType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function prePersist(){
        $this->myService->myFunction($this->getParent()->getSubject()->getId());
    }
}
```

How can I access the parent entity?

Comment: Is the `id` autogenerated and without a setter method in the entity class?

Comment: It is auto generated. I could use getSubject from parent but there's a bug I guess, has to do with https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3747

Comment: If it is autogenerated then it has no setter method. Then it has lost nothing in the form. What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: On creating the `basketElement` I also need to call a service which requires the parent `basket` entity. If I understand correct this should be done with `getParent` in the `basketElementAdmin` but `getParent` always returns null. It seems to me that there's no link between the `BasketAdmin` and the `BasketElementAdmin`. The url which loads the `BasketElementAdmin` only contains an `uniqid` and `puniqid` but that `puniqid` isn't used in php code.

Comment: This is a classical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please add that information to your question, explain what you actually want to achieve, add all other relevant code, like the service. Eventually your problem can be solved with a completely another approach, maybe using the `prePersist` *lifecycleCallback*.

Comment: Updated the example and explanation (also I've learned more and digged deeper). Thanks for the hint! Already came across prePersist on the admin class but I'm not able to get the parent basket entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found 2 solutions;

- `link_parameters` can be added to `fieldDescriptionOptions` argument of the `add` method on the `CollectionType` field. Than in the basketElementAdmin one can retrieve the link parameter from the request object and use it to retrieve the linked entity.

```
    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper): void
        {
            $formMapper->with('basket.group.basketElements')
                ->add('basketElements', Sonata\Form\Type\CollectionType::class, [], [
                    'link_parameters' => ['basket_id' => $this->getSubject()->getId()]
                ])
            ;
        }
    }
```

- The function of service which needs the parent id can be called and set to the childAdmin in the `prePersist` and `preUpdate` methods of the parent admin